# [NSDateFormatter class]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdateformatter

what is the problem in code below?

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
error.timestamp =  [formatter stringFromDate:date];
[formatter release];
```

I am getting this error below:

```
 *** -[NSDateFormatter class]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x8c04f00
```

How can I resolve it?

I don't use ARC.

Comment: error.timestamp =  [[formatter stringFromDate:date]copy]; and then check

Comment: @Popeye, No. I updated my question. Thanks for  indicating.

Comment: code seems to correct. On which line you're getting this error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you posted seems to be correct.
Are you sure you are getting the message from the code you posted?
Can you set an [exception breakpoint in Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) to check if the above code is the problem?

If you are not re-using NSDateFormatter, you could use the following class method to get a date string in one line of code:

```
[NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:date dateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle]
```